# How can i mock i base method when test derived class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have the problem that i want to write a unit test of a custom function in my user service. But this user service derives from asp.net core identity user manager. I want to extend the functionality of the user manager therefore i derived from it. 
So I want to test the method *CreateCRohMUserAsync*

```
    public class UserService : UserManager<User>, IUserService
{
    public UserService(IUserStore<User> store,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<User>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>> passwordValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<User>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateCRohMUserAsync(User user)
    {
        PasswordGenerator pwGenerator = new PasswordGenerator();
        var password = pwGenerator.Generate();

        user.UserName = GetUniqueUserName(user.FirstName, user.LastName);

        var result = await base.CreateAsync(user, password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //TODO: send mail to created user                
        }

        return result;
    }


    public string GetUniqueUserName(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName), "firstName can not be null");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lastName), "lastName can not be null");
        }

        return lastName + firstName.Substring(0, 2) + Users.Count() + 1;
    }
}
```

}

In my unit test i want to mock the *base.CreateAsync(user,password)* and the *Users.Count()* functionality of my base class. But I don't know how to do this.
Or is my implementation wrong? How can I unit test this mehtod?

Comment: Is `CreateAsync` `virtual`? Would be great if you could provide more information about the base class. Also which mocking framework are you using?

Comment: `CreateAsync` is virutal. It is implemented in the class of `namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` here ist class: `public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class`

Comment: Ah okay, then you can just mock your `UserService` class. What mocking framework are you using? If you let me know I can write up an example test for you.

Comment: first i tried @JeremyTCD way but now i changed to weichch way. now it works

Comment: @SilvesterSchn. @JeremyTCD answer should work if you change your call from `base.CreateAsync` to `CreateAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example code, I'd recommend you change the inheritance to composition as you only use methods from the base class, not override any.

```
interface IUserManager
{
    IdentityResult CreateAsync();
}

class DefaultUserManager : IUserManager
{
    public DefaultUserManager(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
    }

    public IdentityResult CreateAsync()
    {
        // Call UserManager<User>
    }
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;

    public UserService(IUserManager userManager, ...)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateCRohMUserAsync(User user)
    {
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I would abstract out the use of `UserManager<User>` into an interface called `IUserManager`, and the implementation still uses `UserManager<User>`. Your `UserService` however calls the interface, so that in your unit test, you could simply provide a mocked instance of `IUserManager` and avoid calling `UserManager<User>`.

Answer (score 2):

Asumming you're using [moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4).

First you'll have to remove the `base` keyword in `CreateCRohMUserAsync`:

```
var result = await CreateAsync(user, password); // Previously base.CreateAsync
```

If it's present, the base class's implementation is always called - mocking `CreateAsync` will have no effect (moq mocks methods by overriding them).

After removing `base`, you can test `CreateCRohMUserAsync` like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async void CreateCRohMUserAsync_DoesSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    ...
    Mock<UserService> mockTestSubject = new Mock<UserService>(...); // Pass services you'd normally pass to the UserService constructor
    mockTestSubject.CallBase = true; // So when you call CreateCRohMUserAsync, the logic you defined runs
    mockTestSubject.Setup(t => t.CreateAsync(...)).ReturnsAsync(...); // Mock CreateAsync
    // If GetUniqueUserName is virtual, you can mock it too    
    // mockTestSubject.Setup(t => t.GetUniqueUserName(...)).Returns(...);

    // Act
    IdentityResult result = await mockTestSubject.Object.CreateCRohMUserAsync(...);

    // Assert
    ...
}
```

The same pattern will work for `GetUniqueUserName`.

Essentially:

- Mock your derived class so you can setup virtual members of your base class.
- Set `CallBase` to true so you can run logic you defined in your derived class.

Comment: This might not work as expected because the OP is explicitly calling the `CreateAsync` method of the base class `base.CreateAsync`. Mock can't mock this type of calls as it is not part of the current class.

Comment: I commented under the question how this solution could work if the OP changes the call.

Comment: @weichch Thanks for the correction. He'll need to remove `base` for this method to work. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I implemented @weichch suggestion and i like it very well. But I also like answer of JeremyTCD. I think both are correct